# MvvmCross ShowViewModel from within Start()

Tags: android, exception, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross 4.2.3 and I have a query about when it is safe to call ShowViewModel

I am trying to call ShowViewModel to navigate in the Start method of ViewModelA to navigate to ViewModelB, however I get the following exception

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

I assumed I was doing it too early in the lifecycle of ViewA\ViewModelA. So I put the call into the OnResume of ViewA. I assumed at this point any transactions required to show ViewA would have been commited.

But I still get the same error.

Has anyone come accross this problem. If so how do I solve it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not being specific here , just trying to solve what you asked .

I think there could be two scenario .

scenerio first .
you want to navigate on user interaction lets say tapping on a button .

Inside view you can put this code in OnCreate or ViewModelSet method overrides .

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(MyButton).For(zz => zz.BindClick()).To(vm => vm.MyCommand);
```

Inside your viewmodel, you would need this .

```
        private ICommand myCommand;
    public virtual ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return myCommand = myCommand ?? new MvxCommand(() => {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    ShowViewModel<MyNextViewModel>();
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Scenario 2 ,

You have some Async task going on based on completion of that you want to navigate .

Inside your viewmodel constructor you call a method like below  .

```
Public MyViewModel(){
LoadActivation()
}

 private  async void LoadActivation() 
{
await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
 try {
    response = await _Myservice.LoadMyData();
    if(response != null ) {
       ShowViewModel<MyNextViewModel>():
     }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
  Debug.WriteLine(ex);
}
                });
    }
```